# conda: set environment specific channels in environment.yml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

If I specify `channels:` in my `env.yml` file, the packages used for the env creation are indeed from this channel.

```
$ cat env.yml 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
```

Create env:

```
$ conda env create -n test -f env.yml
$ conda activate test
```

The packages are installed though the correct channel:

```
$ conda list 
# packages in environment at /home/mathurin/anaconda3/envs/test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
```

But when, inside this env, I later install other packages, they are still from the defaults channels:

```
$ conda config --show channels 
channels:
  - defaults
```

How can I tell conda to set, once and for all, the channels to something for this env, and can it be done inside the `environement.yml` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible through a YAML. However, one can set environment-specific configuration settings.

```
conda activate test
conda config --env --append channels conda-forge --append channels nodefaults
```

The key this is the `--env` argument: This edits a `.condarc` in the `envs/test/` directory, which will take precedence over any system- or user-level `.condarc`. However, both `.condarc` files will be loaded, so if you explicitly have `defaults` in your `~/.condarc`, it will still show up after the environment-specific ones.